# Freeze header does not allow to click knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following html snippet

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="background-color:white!important" data-bind="visible:!loading(),fixedHeader:loading">
  <thead >
    <tr>
      <th data-bind="click:sortSurname">Surname
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'surname'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </th>
      <th data-bind="click:sortName">Name
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'name'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </th>
      <th data-bind="click:sortTitle">Business Title
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'title'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'title'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </th>
      <th data-bind="click:sortOrganization">Organization
        <!-- ko if:whatToSort() == 'organization'-->
          <i class="fa fa-caret-up" data-bind="visible:ascending"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" data-bind="visible:!ascending()"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot:whatToSort() == 'organization'-->
          <i class="fa fa-sort fa-pos-conf" ></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:sorteddata">
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text:surname"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text:name"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text:title"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text:organization"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following View Model:

```
function CompanyViewModel()
{
  var list=this;
  list.data=ko.observableArray([
                                    new BusinessMen({id:1,name:"john",surname:"doe",title:"Harem Maker",organization:"Harem Ltd"}),
                                    new BusinessMen({id:2,name:"Alan",surname:"doe",title:"CEO",organization:"Harem Ltd"}),
                                    new BusinessMen({id:1,name:"miss",surname:"piggy",title:"Piug Manager",organization:"Pig Ltd"}),
                                    ....
                                    new BusinessMen({id:1,name:"Bill",surname:"Gates",title:"MIcrosoft's Former CEO",organization:"Microsoft Inc"}),
                                  ]);
  list.whatToSort=ko.observable('surname'); //Tell with what to sort the table
  list.ascending=ko.observable(false); //Tell the order to sort
  /**
  *Callback for sorting
  */
  var sortFunc=function(a,b)
  {
    switch(list.whatToSort())
    {
      case 'name':
      a=a.name;
      b=b.name;
      break;
      case 'title':
      a=a.title;
      b=b.title;
      break;
      case 'organization':
      a=a.organization;
      b=b.organization;
      break;
      case 'surname':
      default:
      a=a.surname;
      b=b.surname;
    }

    if(!list.ascending())//Swap if desceding
    {
      var temp=b;
      b=a;
      a=temp;
    }

    if(typeof a ==='undefined' || typeof b === 'undefined') return 0;
    return ( ( a() == b() ) ? 0 : ( ( a() > b() ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
  };

  list.sortSurname=function()
  {
    list.whatToSort('surname');
    list.ascending(!list.ascending());
  };

  list.sortName=function()
  {
    list.whatToSort('name');
    list.ascending(!list.ascending());
  }
  list.sortOrganization=function()
  {
    list.whatToSort('organization');
    list.ascending(!list.ascending());
  }

  list.sortTitle=function()
  {
    list.whatToSort('title');
    list.ascending(!list.ascending());
  }

  /**
  *Sorted Data depending what we select
  */
  list.sorteddata=ko.pureComputed(function()
  {
    return list.data().sort(sortFunc);
  });

  function BusinessMen(data)
  {
    var buinessman=this;
    data.id=parseInt(data.id);
    data.name=ko.observable(data.name);
    data.surname=ko.observable(data.surname);
    data.title=ko.observable(data.title);
    data.organization=ko.observable(data.organization);
  }
}
```

And finally the binding Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fixedHeader={
    update:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
     $(element).freezeHeader({offset : '50px'});
    }
};
```

The code above displays a fixed header on top of a table using freezeheader.js (https://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/) and knockout.js.

The problem is that when I scroll down and the "frozen" header is displayed  I cannot sort the data, particullary when I click on the header to select a sort key then no item is executed and I do not know why does this happen.

Maybe some help please;

Comment: Freezeheader seems to clone your header. When knockout applies its bindings, it starts listening to clicks on the initial table header. Once this header is cloned and appended to the DOM elsewhere, bindings aren't transfered.

Comment: Do you have an Idea how to transfer bindings too?

Comment: There's a pull request here that might fix the issue: https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/pull/8/commits/90481bc39f86b9e5fc9df8bd4cfa40aa791c63df

By using jQuery's `.clone(true)`, the element _and_ its event listeners are cloned. I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to do it, but it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/auznogt0/

Comment: In any case, if you add code to your question, be sure to make it minimal (but enough to repro though). This is quite a lot of irrelevant code to go through for us to hunt for the issue.

Comment: @user3297291 Your comments might even be an answer, non? Please consider posting it as one.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks for helping out. I've rewritten my comments into an (hopefully) clear answer. Still new to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Freezeheader library uses a clone of your data bound DOM element to display the sticky header at the top of your viewport. The way it appends this clone to the DOM is:

```
tabela.append('<thead>' + obj.header.html() + '</thead>');
```

([source (line 107)](https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/blob/master/js/jquery.freezeheader.js#L107))

A cloned HTML element might look similar to its original element, but it looses all connection to event listeners or, in your case, the knockout data-bind context.

jQuery's `clone` method has an option that lets you copy not just the raw HTML, but also any event listeners attached to it. Use it by passing a `true` argument: `element.clone(true)` gives you a copy *with* copied event listeners. ([source](https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents))

You're not the first Freezeheader user that encountered this problem. Github user Shafranov issued [a pull request](https://github.com/laertejjunior/freezeheader/pull/8/commits/90481bc39f86b9e5fc9df8bd4cfa40aa791c63df) that replaces the line of code shown below with jQuery's `clone(true)` approach.

Before you make this change, please make sure you're not breaking any other data-binds. While jQuery might copy the click listener for you, it'll probably not enable knockout to update texts or values at two locations in the DOM from one viewmodel.